# SQL Insert error Column name or number of supplied values

Tags: sql-server

I have one of the stored procedures for my replication giving this error

> Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied value does not match table definition".

The stored procedure is spInsertsrra and the table is srra, I have put the syntax below for the 2 articles.

```
       CREATE PROCEDURE SpInsertSrra @num_SessIdSession NUMERIC(10),
                                      @tin_SrraCptAnom1  TINYINT,
                                     @tin_SrraCptAnom2  TINYINT,
                                     @tin_SrraCptAnom3  TINYINT,
                                     @tin_SrraCptAnom4  TINYINT,
                                     @tin_SrraCptAnom5  TINYINT,
                                    @tin_SrraCptAnom6  TINYINT,
                                    @tin_SrraCptAnom7  TINYINT
AS
    INSERT INTO srra
    VALUES      (@num_SessIdSession,
                 @tin_SrraCptAnom1,
                 @tin_SrraCptAnom2,
                 @tin_SrraCptAnom3,
                 @tin_SrraCptAnom4,
                 @tin_SrraCptAnom5,
                 @tin_SrraCptAnom6,
                 @tin_SrraCptAnom7)

GO 

CREATE TABLE [SRRA] (
[SESS_ID_SESSION] [numeric](10, 0) NOT NULL ,
[SRRA_CPT_ANOM1] [tinyint] NULL ,
[SRRA_CPT_ANOM2] [tinyint] NULL ,
[SRRA_CPT_ANOM3] [tinyint] NULL ,
[SRRA_CPT_ANOM4] [tinyint] NULL ,
[SRRA_CPT_ANOM5] [tinyint] NULL ,
[SRRA_CPT_ANOM6] [tinyint] NULL ,
[SRRA_CPT_ANOM7] [tinyint] NULL ,
[rowguid]  uniqueidentifier ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL CONSTRAINT
           [DF__SRRA__rowguid__5F94079C] DEFAULT (newid()),
       CONSTRAINT [PK_SRRA] PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED 
           (
    [SESS_ID_SESSION]
         )  ON [PRIMARY] ,
         CONSTRAINT [FK_SRRA_CPTRS_ANO_SESS_SAN] FOREIGN KEY 
         (
    [SESS_ID_SESSION]
        ) REFERENCES [SESS_SANTE] (
    [SESS_ID_SESSION]
     )
          ) ON [PRIMARY]
          GO
```

Comment: I wondered who voted my question down. What is wrong in the question?

Comment: And the definition of `srra` is? Also, if you have insert triggers, go ahead and post them + the table structure of what *they* reference

Comment: Thanks bilinkc. I am not the developer of the database, but i checked the SP and tables and nothing like srra. I am not an expert on SP, but I have looked for the reference somehow but do not knwo how to get that.

Comment: @oshaye3 Can you find the definition of `srra` (the `CREATE TABLE` statement)?

Comment: OK I have put it in the question is too long

Comment: Isn't it obvious now? The CREATE TABLE shows 9 columns, the INSERT only 8 (the `rowguid` is missing).

Comment: Missing the 9th column is fine because it has a default constraint, but in order to do that, the column list has to be specified.

Comment: So should I add this to the INSERT:  @tin_rowguid)

Comment: @oshaye3 - No. Either of the approaches in the two answers will work to give the new row the column default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SRRA has 9 columns, but you're only inserting 8. Specify `DEFAULT` for your rowguid column.

```
INSERT INTO srra
    VALUES      (@num_SessIdSession,
                 @tin_SrraCptAnom1,
                 @tin_SrraCptAnom2,
                 @tin_SrraCptAnom3,
                 @tin_SrraCptAnom4,
                 @tin_SrraCptAnom5,
                 @tin_SrraCptAnom6,
                 @tin_SrraCptAnom7,
                 DEFAULT)
```

Comment: Thanks db2. It is working and I used the Default has suggested. The DB developer omitted this in their design and so gives insert error during replication. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You aren't supplying a value for all the columns and so need an explicit column list.

```
INSERT INTO SRRA
            (SESS_ID_SESSION,
             SRRA_CPT_ANOM1,
             SRRA_CPT_ANOM2,
             SRRA_CPT_ANOM3,
             SRRA_CPT_ANOM4,
             SRRA_CPT_ANOM5,
             SRRA_CPT_ANOM6,
             SRRA_CPT_ANOM7)
VALUES      (@num_SessIdSession,
             @tin_SrraCptAnom1,
             @tin_SrraCptAnom2,
             @tin_SrraCptAnom3,
             @tin_SrraCptAnom4,
             @tin_SrraCptAnom5,
             @tin_SrraCptAnom6,
             @tin_SrraCptAnom7)
```

`ROWGUIDCOL` columns don't behave like `IDENTITY` columns in this respect.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I understand now. I just used Default and it has worked. This has been affecting replication, but now is working. Cheers!